# Cannot connect IBM data studio with DB2 Express-C (Error: User Id Revoked)

Tags: db2, database-connection, ibm-data-studio

I have installed following software in the order:
1. IBM DB2 Express C version 10.5.1
2. IBM Data Studio version 4.1.0.1

I am having local admin rights.
I have installed both above software using my corporate domain account (SomeDomain\BharatMori)

While installing Express-C, I have created a user – ‘db2admin’. I am quite positive on credentials so there is no chance that I am providing wrong credentials.

Now, when I am trying to connect using Data Studio, it was not allowing me. So, I have connected to database using command line and created new database "TEST". Command line did not ask me any credentials. I have created a table - "tests" inside it and added some records in it.

Now, when I am trying to connect TEST database (that is in Local DB2 Express-C) using "Data Studio", following error popped up:

[image: Error from Data Studio]

I am using following configurations to connect to local database:

[image: TEST configurations from Data Studio]

I have created database, table and few records using command-line.
[image: Connecting using command line]

I am not sure why IBM Data Studio is not getting connected to TEST database in DB2 Express-C, while the command line can do it? What is that I am missing? Please guide me.

Comment: Sometimes the problem is with your domain user and local user. That is the problem of the extended security in Windows that I have not understand neither, but this is a clue to find the answer.

Comment: What happens when you connect to your database from the command line as the user `db2admin`?

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to connect Data Studio to the TEST database using the `db2admin` user account and password.  This is typically a Windows user account created during DB2 installation that owns the DB2 application code, services and registry keys.  While you *can* use that account for database administration, I typically use another account that belongs to Windows' Administrators group for that purpose.  You can find more information about this at:

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.sec.doc/doc/c0023391.html

When you log in at the command-line, however, you're not specifying a username or password, so you're being logged into DB2 under whatever username and password you're logged into Windows with, which I assume is not `db2admin`.  While I can't say why you can't access the TEST database you created from the command line from db2admin account, know that in any case you're trying to access the same database with two different users, so it's entirely possible that one has permission to do so while the other doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

In the DB2 Connection Profile, try this:

```
User = BharatMori
Password = <login password for BharatMori>
```

this should work. You are using the same credentials with Command Line. Hence it allows there.